# How to combine multiple scripts into one script in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Here are my scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/btgAportion.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tab.js"></script>

script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery_calc.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery_onload.js"></script>

<script src="../js/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script src="../js/collapsible.js"></script>
```

They all are in common js folder
I want to combine all these scripts into one script  to reduce HTTP requests

Comment: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Comment: not needed just minify individual file enable gzip compression

Comment: @ArunKillu _not needed_ but a _good practice_ for user/seo-friendly applications.

Comment: Is there any way to minify js files before building a war file, as minified files are not so user friendly to read?

Comment: @jeetZ Do users read the js files? Curious developers do and you shouldn't be worried about them :)

Comment: Developer should edit that file if issue occured.Again asking is there any method to minify all the js file before building a war file to deploy?

Comment: @ArunKillu Is there any way to minify js files before building a war file, as minified files are not so user friendly to read?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches. Edit, if you're going to downvote me, let me at least say, this tool of mine is a java tool for aggregating javascript files together for exactly the purpose you want:
http://damonsmith.github.io/js-class-loader/

Otherwise, if you want to roll your own JSP based solution, you can create a scripts.jsp which reads each one and just concatenates them all together into the output, then use that scripts.jsp inside your HTML script tag. It's probably easier for small sites than my over-engineered tooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/dfsq/compressJS.sh shell script to compress multiple JS files to one.

From official ReadMe:

> Very simple bash script which compresses javascript files with Google
>   Closure Compiler and then make a single file of them. Reduce file
>   sizes and save bandwidth with just one simple command.

Answer (score -1):

Reduce number of HTTP round-trips by combining multiple JavaScript resources into one.
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/CombineJavaScript

compress javascripts by using : http://jscompress.com/

Comment: link only answers are not encouraged here!!

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, please expand your answer and show/explain how multiple script files can be combined into a single request.